# Blazor Pass EventCallback from RenderFragment to templated component

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

Hi Need help on eventcallback from RederFragment Component to Parent Method below is the code snippet

GenericList  component

```html
@typeparam TItem

@foreach (var item in Items)
{
    @ChildContent(item)
}


@code {

    [Parameter] public List<TItem> Items { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TItem> ChildContent { get; set; }

    void DeleteItem(TItem item)
    {
        Items.Remove(item);
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}
```

phone component

```html
<InputText @bind-Value="NewPhone.PhoneNumber"></InputText>

@code {
    public Phone NewPhone { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<Phone> DeletePhone { get; set; }

    public class Phone
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

now when i use GenericList Component, how do i pass EventCallback DeletePhone to Delete Method on GenericList

```html
<GenericListComponent Items="PhoneList" TItem=Phone>
    <ChildContent Context="phone">
        <PhoneComponent Phone="phone" DeletePhone=**"?"**></PhoneComponent>
    </ChildContent>
</GenericListComponent>
```

Comment: any update on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing but unfortunately it seems that EventCallbacks are not supported. Or so it says in MS documentation.
[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#child-content-render-fragments